# How to import bitcoins from one wallet to another wallet?

Tags: transactions, wallet, transaction-fees

I have purchased some fractional bitcoins from a website zebpay.com in india. I want to transfer those bitcoins to a wallet name jaxx so that i can buy ethereuem and other cryptocurrencies from jaxx wallet.

I can send bitcoin from zebpay to jaxx by pasting jaxx's bitcoin address in zebpay, but i have to pay transaction commission fee to zebpay for that. Is there any other way that i can just open my bitcoin in jaxx without giving any type of transaction fees?

Answer (score -1):

Well you want to make a transaction from one wallet to another, and for someone to bother mine that transaction they should get paid that small fee.